# Creating GeoJSON from DBF file

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, dbf

Can I create GeoJSON from DBF where X and Y coordinates are stored as normal attributes.

Is there something in `ogr2ogr`, which can create GeoJSON?

[Example DBF file link:](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiyXW6c9-EEdipNsQOjQ0JtCStCDJg)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to convert a dbf file to a GeoJSON one thanks to the power of Spatialite support:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON StackOverFlowExample.json StackOverFlowExample.dbf -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_Point(x,y) AS geometry, * FROM StackOverFlowExample"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the .dbf is not part of an ESRI shp I think your best option is converting the dbf to csv and then the csv to geojson. You could use ogre or the many online available sites.